# View goes up after dismissing modal view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a simple project with NavBar and ToolBar. My code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    [toolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
    [toolBar setTranslucent:YES];

    addPhotoItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add photo" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showActionSheet)];
    NSArray *itemsArray = @[ addPhotoItem ];
    [toolBar setItems:itemsArray];
    [toolBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, self.view.frame.size.height-44.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, 44.0f)];
    [self.view addSubview:toolBar];

    [navBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, 44.0f)];
    [navBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
    [navBar setTranslucent:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:navBar];
}
```

In my toolBar I have one button which open ActionSheet with 2 options: get image from camera and from library. My code:

```
- (void)getMediaFromSource:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType {
    self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
    self.imagePicker.sourceType = sourceType;
    [self presentModalViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES];
}
```

But after dismissing modal controller my parent view goes up for 44pt (approximately). How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

u dont need to set the frame of toolbar, just add this in viewDidLoad

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

and it will bring up the toobar, dont add it manually as a subView and u can add the UIBarButtonItem as

```
self.navigationController.toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:addPhotoItem, nil];
```

and u are done.

u can hide the toolbar again by setting the parameter as `YES` in `setToolbarHidden`

i hope it helped. happy coding :)

Comment: Can I do this even if I doesn't use UINavigationController application?

Comment: no it exists only in case of UINavigationController and u have mentioned that u have a navBar.

Comment: I have navBar but I added it by himself